awaitCancellation() not working on InterceptPlatformTextInput after a BasicTextField without InterceptPlatformTextInput with awaitCancellation()
When I have a BasicTextField inside a InterceptPlatformTextInput with awaitCancellation to prevent softkeyboard from showing, it still shows the softkeyboard if a previous BasicTextField on the same Activity without this restriction got focused and showed the softkeyboard. I'm using Jetpack Compose 1.7.0-beta01 libraries.
I did an example code to illustrate my problem.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            InputInterceptTestTheme {
                Fields()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Fields() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = "Field 1: NO KEYBOARD")
        TestTextField(textFieldState = TextFieldState(), showKeyboard = false)

        Text(text = "Field 2: SHOW KEYBOARD")
        TestTextField(textFieldState = TextFieldState(), showKeyboard = true)

        Text(text = "Field 3: NO KEYBOARD")
        TestTextField(textFieldState = TextFieldState(), showKeyboard = false)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun TestTextField(
    textFieldState: TextFieldState,
    showKeyboard: Boolean,
) {
    InterceptPlatformTextInput(interceptor = { request, nextHandler ->
        if (showKeyboard) {
            nextHandler.startInputMethod(request)
        } else {
            awaitCancellation()
        }
    }) {
        BasicTextField(
            state = textFieldState,
            lineLimits = TextFieldLineLimits.SingleLine,
            textStyle = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                letterSpacing = 2.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace
            ),
            decorator = {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                        .border(1.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    it()
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

On this example, Field 1 and 3 are with the restriction, and Field 2 will show the softkeyboard. If I click on the Field 1 or 3 first, they won't show the softkeyboard. But if I click on the Field 2 first, and then on the field 1 or 3, they will show the softkeyboard, even with InterceptPlatformTextInput going to the awaitCancellation() route.
I don't understand much of InputConnections. I think as they are on the same activity, they share some kind of input session between the fields, but I don't know how to prevent this behavior. How can I prevent softkeyboard from showing on a BasicTextField after another BasicTextField showed it on the same activity?

Have you found a solution to this problem?

@erksch they fixed this bug on androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.8.0-alpha01. It is currently on 1.8.0-alpha04.
